# Google Oauth2 - Call to Token

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, oauth-2.0

I am reading though the Google API and it says to:

"The first step is to call loadCredential(String) based on the known user ID to check if the end-user's credentials are already known. If not, call newAuthorizationUrl() and direct the end-user's browser to an authorization page. The web browser will then redirect to the redirect URL with a "code" query parameter which can then be used to request an access token using newTokenRequest(String). Finally, use createAndStoreCredential(TokenResponse, String) to store and obtain a credential for accessing protected resources."

So I place the line of code in my code, and it fails even with proper import statements. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Credential to AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl"

```
AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl bob2 = AuthorizationCodeFlow.loadCredential("test"); or
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow bob2 = AuthorizationCodeFlow.loadCredential("test");
```

http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.7.0-beta/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/AuthorizationCodeFlow.html?is-external=true#loadCredential%28java.lang.String%29

Also, if anyone has any good example for Oauth2 implementations for Google, please post them.  The only one I can find that I can understand (see link below) seems depreciated, and I want to use the latest version.  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-authorization-callback-handler

Comment: Your link to developers.google.com isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

sHere is the code I used.  It is not a complete example, but it should give someone the idea.

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
   // response.getWriter().println(" User " + user);
    if (user == null) {
        response.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(getFullRequestUrl(request)));


        return;
      }
```

Then I get the authorization code no matter what.  (Bad coding.)

```
response.sendRedirect(new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(oauthProperties2.getClientId(), OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.getOAuthCodeCallbackHandlerUrl(request), oauthProperties2.getScopesAsString()).build());
```